# How to set the duration time in the "Generate Workspace Preview Link" in typo3 4.5.25? It's possible?

Tags: typo3

How to set the duration time in the "Generate Workspace Preview Link" in typo3 4.5.25? 
It's possible? By default duration is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the UserTSConfig:

```
options.workspaces.previewLinkTTLHours = x (x in hours)
```

This should work for typo3 4.5 up to 6.2

or search '24 * 2' in `typo3/sysext/version/cm1` (typo3 4.5) or (typo3 6.x) in  `typo3/sysext/version/Classes/Hook/PreviewHook.php` look at the function `getPreviewLinkLifetime()`

The third way is to manipulate the field `endtime` in table `sys_preview` for a single link